# Duplicate background colors in bootstrap's css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have found the following css declaration in twitter bootstrap ([link](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) and [source](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/grid.css)). Basically it declares the following:

```
background-color: #eee;
background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
```

As far as you see - there is a duplicated background color and border. If it would be anywhere else, I would ignore it thinking 'these guys just do not know css'.

But because this is highly used open-source project, done by professionals, I have a pending question: is it really a bug or does it make sense (if so can someone explain to me why someone would use it?).

Comment: The primary declarations treat as fallback for the next ones. Because `rgba()` is not supported is IE8 and lower, ... http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: Cool, thank you for explanation. Can you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`rgba()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color) color value has been introduced in CSS level 3 specification.

It declares colors in *Red-green-blue* model including *alpha*, allowing specification of the opacity of colors.

`rgba()` is not supported [in old web browsers](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) such as IE8, Opera9, ... Thus, developers use a solid color as a fallback.

In this particular instance, the primary declarations treat as fallback for the next ones:

```css
background-color: #eee;  /* The Fallback */
background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);

border: 1px solid #ddd;  /* The Fallback */
border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
```

If a web browser supports `rgba()` the second declaration will override the first one. But if the web browser doesn't understand `rgba()` color, the second declaration will be ignored, Thus the first one will be appled to the element(s).

However there are some alternatives you might want to consider:

- [Bulletproof, cross-browser RGBA backgrounds, today](http://lea.verou.me/2009/02/bulletproof-cross-browser-rgba-backgrounds/)
- [CSS Transparency Settings for All Browsers](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/)